# When I apply vlc on the web, my computer's CPU becomes 100%. What should I do?

Tags: vlc

We applied VLC with Object tag. Up to 10 object tags with the same RTSP are CPU stable. However, if the number of Object tags increases by 12 or more, the CPU becomes 100%. What should I do???

```html
<div id="object_container">        
  <object type="application/x-vlc-plugin"                         
    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" id="vlc21" width="517" 
    height="388" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-
    BE1D1C159921">
    <param name="MRL" id="mrlVideo" value="" />
    <param name="volume" value="50" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="True" />
    <param name="loop" value="false" />
    <param name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="toolbar" value="true" />
    <param name="windowless" value="true" />
  </object>
</div>
<script>
  var rtst_url = "rtsp://ID:password@ipcamera ip:554/H.264/media.smp";
  var options = [":network-caching=80", ":file-caching=80", ":hevc-fps=-340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000", ":prefetch-buffer-size=250000", ":postproc-q=1", ":goom-width=100", ":goom-height=100", ":sout-chromecast-conversion-quality=3", ":preferred-resolution=240"];
  vlc10.playlist.clear();
  vlc10.playlist.add(rtsp_url,  null , options);
  vlc10.audio.toggleMute();
  vlc10.playlist.play();
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use vlc web plugins. It's not really maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If so, can implementation with WebRTC solve this situation?

Comment: I don't know, try it